# Docker exits with code 0 when using pm2 start

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

My `Dockerfile` contains the `pm2 start` command as follows:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

# ...

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "pm2", "start", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

However the container exits straightaway after pm2 logs successfully starting:

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting /usr/local/bin/npm in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
```

How can I get the container to stay running with pm2?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that `pm2 start` runs pm2 as a daemon ("in the background"), which Docker isn't aware of.

You need to use `pm2-runtime` to make it run in the foreground:

```
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

[See pm2 "Container integration" docs.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2#container-support)

Comment: pm2-runtime also exits with status code 0. I'm using `CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "npm", "--", "dev" ]`
The project is graphql prisma with typescript. This is the package.json's npm dev: `"dev": "ts-node-dev --no-notify --respawn --transpile-only src/server",`

Answer (score 1):

Also faced this issue of immediately stopping container with `pm2-runtime` usage.

I decided to change last line to:

```
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "dist/index.js", "--no-daemon"]
```

That resolved my issue.

Thus, in your case it could be:

```
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "--no-daemon", "npm", "--", "start"]
```